# Broken package in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, ppa

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  fonts-lyx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 112 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main firefox amd64 53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [46.1 MB]
Fetched 46.1 MB in 36s (1,249 kB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Below are the solutions given on ask ubuntu which didn't worked for me.

Solution 1:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Solution 2:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Solution 3:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/firefox_53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo dpkg --install firefox_53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb
```

Solution 4:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -rvf
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Solution 5:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: Wait a while for the mirrors to sync up?  This happens frequently when you try to use a mirror that is in mid-sync

Comment: Waited for more than 12 hours. Still the same. What should I do?

Comment: I presume you did a `sudo apt-get update` in the past 12 hours and it's still causing problems?

Comment: Nope. I didn't touched the PC.

Comment: Do another `sudo apt-get update` and then try again.